# Using settype in PHP instead of typecasting using brackets, What is the difference?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

In PHP you can typecast something as an object like this; (object) or you can use settype($var, "object") - but my question is what is the difference between the two?

Which one is more efficient / better to use? At the moment I find using (object) does the job, but wondering why there is a settype function as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Casting changes what the variable is being treated as in the current context, settype changes it permanently.

```
$value = "100"; //Value is a string
echo 5 + (int)$value; //Value is treated like an integer for this line
settype($value,'int'); //Value is now an integer
```

Basically settype is a shortcut for:

```
$value = (type)$value;
```

Comment: So really it's best to just use (type) instead of settype then? Are there performance advantages of using (type) over settype() or are they both the same?

Comment: Performance really shouldnt be an issue in the first place, trust me. You could however run your own tests using microtime.

Comment: @KristofferSall-Storgaard
You answer is confusing me.
In the first sentence you write that settype  changes it permanently which isn't true.
settype change the datatype as long as there isn't a new assignment which requires another datatype. 

In your second sentence you write the correct answer "Basically settype is a shortcut for:".
So it doesn't matter which version you choose.
Seems to me that it is another part of syntax sugar the world doesn't need.

Answer (score 7):

`settype()` alters the actual variable it was passed, the parenthetical casting does not.

If you use `settype` on `$var` to change it to an integer, it will permanently lose the decimal portion:

```
$var = 1.2;
settype($var, "integer");
echo $var; // prints 1, because $var is now an integer, not a float
```

If you just do a cast, the original variable is unchanged.

```
$var = 1.2;
$var2 = (integer) $var;
echo $var; // prints 1.2, because $var didn't change type and is still a float
echo $var2; // prints 1
```

Comment: It is a thinking error in their code.
With $var2 = (integer) $var; first the value of $var is assigned to the new variable $var2 and only then the data type is changed to int. If you had used the same variable, it would now also be int.

Like many other dynamic programming languages, PHP uses a data structure for variables called zval.
In it the value is stored together with the data type.
This info is used to work with the value.

Therefore PHP needs a bit more memory during runtime than the same programming in a compiler language like C which PHP is internally based on.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that settype does NOT change the variable type permanently. The next time you set the value of the variable, PHP will change its type as well.

```
$value = "100"; //Value is a string
echo 5 + (int)$value; //Value is treated like an integer for this line
settype($value,'int'); //Value is now an integer
$value = "Hello World"; //Now value is a string
$value = 7; // Now value is an integer
```

Type Juggling can be frustrating but if you understand what's happening and know your options it can be managed. Use var_dump to get the variables type and other useful info.

Comment: Casting won't change it permanently either.
see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cab3255dfbd5c4a229c0715c2c8b9f1150771deb