# PHP When to use settype

Tags: php, pdo, type-conversion

PHP has auto type conversion function, but when do we ever need to use `settype()`? 
The only example I have tried that needs `settype()` is when I need to put data from users to the database using PDO, where attributes are defined as int, decimal, or etc. I need to first convert the type (from `string` to `int`  for example and when I do not use `settype()`, it seems to have error coming out.) BUT are there any other reasons why people gonna use `settype()`? Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Maybe many just misunderstand my question. Let me re-phase it. 
When do I ever need to use settype() since PHP auto converse type when it is needed? For example, PHP will not convert data type when inserting data into database. Therefore we should use a settype() to convert data to the specified type. If not, error will be raised.

Can anyone give me more example other than connecting to the database where settype() is needed? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577003/using-settype-in-php-instead-of-typecasting-using-brackets-what-is-the-differen. You should use prepared statements in PDO though..

Comment: Sorry... maybe you misinterpret my question. I wanna ask when will I use settype(), instead of the difference between type conversion and settype().

Comment: So the question is more why would you cast a variable in PHP?

Comment: It just casts the variable. It is the same as casting in any other way (e.g. `$a=(int)$a);` or `$a=intval($a);`). It just modifies the variable in place, so you do not have to reassign a casted value.